# Solve $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{{2n+1}}\sqrt{(25-a^2)n^2+2n+3}=2$ for $a$

Tags: limits

Solve following equation involving limit for $a$ unknown.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{{2n+1}}\sqrt{(25-a^2)n^2+2n+3}=2$$

Hint, please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{(25-a^2)n^2+2n+3}}{2n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{(25-a^2)+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{3}{n^2}}{4+\frac4n+\frac{1}{n^2}}}=\sqrt{\frac{25-a^2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{25-a^2}}{2}$$

I hope you can take it from here!

Comment: You made a small mistake at the end with the $a²$.

Comment: But isn't it a rule of mathematics that when we have $25-a^2$ then $a$ is one of $\pm 3$, $\pm 4$?

Comment: I don't think you should have squared $25-a^2$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, True, and the remark of Michael is here to correct the problem and come back to this rule!

Comment: @Integrator, thank you very much!

Comment: @Integrator, I think you are right now

Comment: Now it finishes nicely, $25-a^2=16$, $a=\pm 3$.

Comment: The poor 5-12-13 triangle never gets any love... :(

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that quadratic term overcome lower terms when $n$ approach infinity.

**Solution:**

> In order to limit to become $2$, $25-a^2$ must be $16$, giving $a=\mp3$.